# Magento 2 How to remove the delete option on magento/admin/catalog/product/index

Tags: magento2, delete

which files should I edit to remove the delete option at action drop-down menu? 
I've tried to remove

```
 $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('catalog/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            ]
        );
```

`\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid.php`, but the `delete` button still appears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 used UI Component to render products grid at admin, you can remove delete action at:
magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml:

comment or remove:

```
<action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete selected items?</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/product/massDelete"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
```

Comment: How do you do this outside of the /vendor file - I've tried copying the file in to my app/code module but removing it just means it uses the one inside /vendor?

Answer (score -1):

I found it! I removed the 'delete' option by editing `\Magento\Catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml`

```
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid.php
```

Comment: Editing core files is baaaaad practice.