# Remove option from adminhtml UI component XML file. Delete Mass Action Option in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to remove (or hide) the delete option from the product listing mass action in the Admin section. I cannot find the correct way to do this.

[This shows how to hack the core files which is not very useful](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94079/magento-2-how-to-remove-the-delete-option-on-magento-admin-catalog-product-index)

[This shows you how to add to the ui component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218823/override-base-ui-component-customer-form-xml?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The file `Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml` is what I would like to override/edit. I have created the custom module and can **add** to the ui component but I cannot simply **remove** the option in `Module/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`
So what am I missing? I have tried simply removing the option in the custom module after copying all of the XML over but that obviously did nothing. How do I Customize the options?

```
   <massaction name="listing_massaction"
                component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions"
                class="\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction">
        <action name="delete">
            <settings>
                <confirm>
                    <message translate="true">Delete selected items?</message>
                    <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                </confirm>
                <url path="catalog/product/massDelete"/>
                <type>delete</type>
                <label translate="true">Delete</label>
            </settings>
        </action>
        <action name="status">
            <settings>
                <type>status</type>
                <label translate="true">Change status</label>
                <actions>
                    <action name="0">
                        <type>enable</type>
                        <label translate="true">Enable</label>
                        <url path="catalog/product/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">1</param>
                        </url>
                    </action>
                    <action name="1">
                        <type>disable</type>
                        <label translate="true">Disable</label>
                        <url path="catalog/product/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">2</param>
                        </url>
                    </action>
                </actions>
            </settings>
        </action>
        <action name="attributes">
            <settings>
                <url path="catalog/product_action_attribute/edit"/>
                <type>attributes</type>
                <label translate="true">Update attributes</label>
            </settings>
        </action>
    </massaction>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using plugin:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction">
        <plugin name="hide_delete_from_catalog_massaction"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Catalog/Ui/Component/Product/MassAction.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product;

class MassAction
{
    public function afterIsActionAllowed(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction $subject,
        $isAllowed,
        $actionType
    ) {
        if ($actionType == 'delete') {
            return false;
        }

        return $isAllowed;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir can you please help me to solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283259/in-magento-2-how-to-get-and-save-a-customer-attributes-value-in-db)

Comment: This worked for me and is the correct way from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

To do this and limit the options to different User Roles I used the answer from [@Sohel-Rana](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4329/sohel-rana) 
and added `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession` to the code.

Module/Plugins/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction">
    <plugin name="module_plugins_magento_catalog_ui_component_product_massaction" type="Module\Plugins\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction"/>
</type>
```

Module/Plugins/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Ui/Component/Product/MassAction.php

```
namespace Module\Plugins\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product;

class MassAction
{
    public function __construct(  \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession)
    {
        $this->_adminSession = $adminSession;
    }

    public function afterIsActionAllowed(

        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction $subject,
        $isAllowed,
        $actionType
    ) {
        $roleData = $this->_adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getData();

        if ($actionType == 'delete' && trim($roleData['role_name'])=='Content-Manager') {
            return false;
        }

        return $isAllowed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution for specific User Roles.