# In magento 2 how to get and save a customer attributes value in db

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer-attribute

In magento 2 how to get and  save a customer attributes value in db

[image: m]

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
         <plugin name="Cm_CustomerAttribute::ShippingInformationManagement" 
 type="Cm\CustomerAttribute\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" 
 sortOrder="1"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php

```
<?php
namespace Cm\CustomerAttribute\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

class ShippingInformationManagement
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
     protected $quoteRepository;
     public function __construct(

    \Cm\CustomerAttribute\Helper\Customerattribute $helper,
     \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {

        $this->helper = $helper;
         $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }


    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
       $shippingAddress = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddressCustomerAttributes = $shippingAddress->getCustomAttributes();
    if ($shippingAddressCustomerAttributes) {
        $customField = $shippingAddressCustomerAttributes->getTestAge();
        $shippingAddress->setTestAge($customField);
     }


    }
```

Custom field value not saved in **db**
[image]

Comment: Are you getting data which you wanted to save ?

Comment: i m posting  a value in checkout page  https://prnt.sc/ojqzkl   and i m asking how to get a customer attributes  values and saved into quote table

Comment: That I know What I'm asking you is are you getting your customer attribute data in conroller,observer etc Whatever you have used !? Or you looking solution how to get those data in file and save to db ?

Comment: I'm looking for how to get a data  and saved into db

Comment: Did you get all the custom attributes in `beforeSaveAddressInformation` function?

Comment: i didn't get any value of customer attributes i just try the above plugin its not working

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Observer After Place Order for that

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="custom_frontend_observer" instance="Vendor/Module\Observer\AfterCheckout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

now in

> Vendor\Module\Observer\AfterCheckout.php

```
/**
 * Class AfterCheckout
 */
class AfterCheckout implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{


    /**
     * Get Current Customer from session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,$collection
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    /**
     * add custom layout updates
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //get Customer Id and DO what you want
    }
    /**
     * Returns Current Customer ID
     * @return Integer
     */
    public function getCusId()
    {
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
            return $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();
        endif;
    }
}
```